# how to fix 'Disable XML external entity (XXE) processing' vulnerabilities in java

Tags: java, xml, sonarqube, owasp

I ran my java code against sonarqube and I got 'Disable XML external entity (XXE) processing' as vulnerability. I spend some time on google to resolve the issue. I have been trying alot of approach but nothing is working for me. I don't know what I'm missing

My Code:

```
        final DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
        docFactory.setFeature(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
        docFactory.setFeature(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);

        docFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
        docFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
        docFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
        docFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

        final DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        final Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
```

I'm using java 1.8, Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40649152/how-to-prevent-xxe-attack

and this rule from Sonar: https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/alexlittle-github/rules?open=squid%3AS2755&rule_key=squid%3AS2755

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, perhaps the checker is just being stupid. Also, what people so often forget is that the XXE vulnerability only applies if you are processing untrusted XML. If you know where the XML came from and trust the code that generated it, XXE is not an issue. Unfortunately though the security people don't always understand that subtlety.

Comment: Hi iCrus. I have tried all those possibilities from sonarqube but still I didn't fixed yet

Answer (score 16):

I end up adding all of the following attributes in order to avoid Sonar complaining about this vulnerability:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

//REDHAT
//https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-15/materials/us-15-Wang-FileCry-The-New-Age-Of-XXE-java-wp.pdf
factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");

//OWASP
//https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
// Disable external DTDs as well
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
// and these as well, per Timothy Morgan's 2014 paper: "XML Schema, DTD, and Entity Attacks"
factory.setXIncludeAware(false);
factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
```

Answer (score 7):

*Java 9+ solution:*

For me changing `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()` to `DocumentBuilderFactory.newDefaultInstance()` was enough to red rid of this warning.

Comment: Don't see the method newDefaultInstance() on javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

Comment: @Anand it was introduced in Java 9.

Comment: With no additionnal information, this sounds more like a way to defeat Sonar's check (e.g. it does not know about this method, so it does not mark it), and not to solve the underlying vulnerability. Basically, it looks like you went and did the just same, but  behind sonar's back. (Once more, without additionnal information).

Comment: @GPI that may be true, I haven't investigate it. If anyone knows the reason behind such behaviour, please feel free to edit the answer adding it

Comment: This solution works with 'XMLInputFactory'. Along with this we need to add the property xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");

Answer (score 5):

It should be enough to just set this two properties:

```
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by adding the below code snippet :

```
saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);    
saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
saxParserFactory.setXIncludeAware(false);
```