# TransformerFactory still vulnerable to XXE attacks

Tags: java, xml, dom4j, xxe

I have a method like below. I've set the FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING to true.

```
    public String getString(org.w3c.dom.Node node) throws TransformerException {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        transformerFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer));

        return writer.toString();
    }
```

When I run my unit test below, I can list the files under project directory, meaning it is vulnerable to XXE attacks.

```
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String dir = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        String xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                        "<!DOCTYPE test[" +
                        "<!ENTITY problemEntity SYSTEM \"" + dir + "\">" +
                        "]>" +
                        "<Response>" +
                        "&problemEntity;" +
                        "</Response>";

        org.w3c.dom.Element node = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()))
                .getDocumentElement();

        String name = getString(node);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

How can I secure the TransformerFactory to such attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supplying a `DOMSource` to the `TransformerFactory`, so the DTD was processed before the `TransformerFactory` came into existence. You need to apply any controls at the point the XML document is parsed, which is when the DOM Node gets created.